# Как получить результаты от поисковика в php?

Tags: php, парсер, синтаксический-анализ, поисковые-системы

Требуется осуществить обработку текстов содержащих некоторое слово. Алгоритм: иду в поисковик и вбиваю слово, читаю предложения с этим словом. Как осуществить на php парсинг(?) результатов поиска хоть какого-нибудь поисковика? Где-то читал про file_get_contents, но не работает. Гугл предлагает API, но как-то непонятно

Comment: А что из себя представляет вот эта часть запроса: ":lo-xv0xuhw8" ?

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю как там у Гугла, а у Яндекса ограничения вообще жестокие, что-то около 1000 запросов в сутки вроде бы. :) Я бы распарсила регулярными выражениями, но это только потому что я их люблю. :) Получать страницу лучше всё же cURL-ом, вы уверены, что он уже не установлен? :) А если и `file_get_contents` запрещён, то нужно срочно менять хостинг-провайдера. :)